# How can I uninstall Windows KB4099989 Update?

Tags: windows-10

I want to uninstall KB4099989 update.
There is no "Uninstall" option in Control Panel -> Installed Updates.
I also tried `wusa /uninstall /kb:4099989 /norestart`, but I've got an error. It says that I can't uninstall it because it is security update.
What to do?

I'm running Windows 10 1709, 16299.371 build.

Comment: What architecture are you running on? As well what edition of Windows 10 / Server 2016?

Comment: No. You can't uninstall a security update.

Comment: Can you restore to a point before the update was installed?

Comment: @AFH yes, but I've done some work after that point. I don't want to lose it. So I'm looking for another way, if it exists. Thanks for an advice by the way.

Comment: There appears to be a way to change the uninstallable flag on the update. I am currently testing it out on a machine before putting an answer with instructions. Since Microsoft made it uninstallable there may be a reason why. Can you provide a screenshot or two with all current updates on the system.

Comment: @CharlesLudlow don't try it, this breaks installation of newer serving stack updates.

Comment: I've tried to recover system via restore point. I got an error after recovering. Now I don't have any restoring points. And I lost near 20 gb of space on system disk. Thanks, Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

KB4099989 is a servicing stack update which can't be uninstalled, because it is blocked my the manifest of the update with the entry `permanence="permanent"`:

> < package identifier="KB4099989" applicabilityEvaluation="deep"
>   releaseType="Update" restart="possible" selfUpdate="true"
>   **permanence="permanent"**>

If you try to remove this and uninstall the update, you can't install newer servicing stack updates.